# What is a method for creating a circle plot using data on 24-hour clock?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a circle plot with the means of a set of data plotted around a center point. The code I have found online does it but the Y axis so big that the graphic isn't useful. I want to limit the Y-axis to 95-120 but when I use `Y_scale_continuous(limit=c(95,120))` it drops the bars.

Data:

```
"","Hour","me"
"1",0,98.9192
"2",1,100.756333333333
"3",2,101.6815
"4",3,98.6551666666667
"5",4,102.668666666667
"6",5,104.024571428571
"7",6,106.137
"8",7,103.6535
"9",8,107.868333333333
"10",9,112.261428571429
"11",10,114.99
"12",11,113.452714285714
"13",12,110.534285714286
"14",13,112.974285714286
"15",14,112.731428571429
"16",15,104.658571428571
"17",16,112.271
"18",17,108.386666666667
"19",18,113.968857142857
"20",19,107.287142857143
"21",20,110.583
"22",21,102.811714285714
"23",22,105.983571428571
"24",23,100.98625
```

Code:

```
p<-ggplot(c, aes(x = Hour, y=me)) + 
         geom_bar(breaks = seq(0,24), width = 2, colour="grey",stat = "identity") +
         theme_minimal() + 
         scale_fill_brewer()+coord_polar(start=0)+
         scale_x_continuous("", limits = c(0, 24), breaks = seq(0, 24), labels = seq(0,24))
```

Comment: Could you include your data in format that can be a copy/pasted into a file for testing?

Comment: `ggplot` enforces that bars start at 0. Maybe just subtract 95 from your data if you want a bar plot that starts somewhere else, and then relabel your axis. (Note that most people find bar plots that don't include 0 misleading.)

Comment: @Gregor The goal here is to show relative value at each hour and show patterns around the 24-hour day. The geom_bar is a means to that end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bars are good at showing proportional changes between values. If you let go of the 0 baseline, they do no longer have that property and this will mislead many people. If a bar is twice is tall, it should encode a value twice as large. `ggplot2` closely follows that philosophy. Consider an alternative visualization. Perhaps a simple line graph:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = Hour, y=me)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill = NA, col = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  coord_polar() +
  scale_x_continuous("", breaks = 0:24, limits = c(0, 24)) +
  ylim(90, 115) # adjust as you like
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the solution here is just to change your data? Mathematically speaking, this accomplishes the same thing as shifting the axis away from zero.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Hour, y=me - 95)) +
  geom_bar(width = 2, colour="grey",stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_brewer() +
  coord_polar(start=0) +
  scale_x_continuous("", limits = c(0, 24), breaks = seq(0, 24), labels = seq(0,24))
```

[image]

This likely makes the chart harder to interpret and therefore you would need to explain any manipulation like this. If the relative values are significant, this can help interpretation, If the absolute values are significant, this kind of adjustment can range from confusing to quite misleading.

Comment: This works. Thanks. What is important here is the relative values. I'm showing how much louder/quiter it is depnding on the hour.

Question, I don't like the overlapping bars but when I change the width to "1" it drops the 00 hour value. Any idea why?