# Is it possible to create a circular timeline plot with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, data-visualization

Is it possible to use ggplot to produce a pie chart of a year (or some other period of time) with wedges that correspond to periods set apart by specific dates (that could then be modified using the rest of ggplot's usual tools)?

Here's a cludged sketch of what I think I'm trying to do: [image: date_pie]

Using the two dates (21 December and 21 March), we could define the purple/blue area to be "winter;" similar things could be done for the other seasons. R already understands dates, so I thought it might be possible for it to plot time periods like this. While this isn't a super-complicated (or even useful) example, I think it could be a useful technique.

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598589/what-is-a-method-for-creating-a-circle-plot-using-data-on-24-hour-clock . It also lacks code to set up a specific instance. SO is not a "code-server". It is instead designed to support persons who are in the middle of a specific project and need some help in getting to the next step.

Comment: While I appreciate seeing that question, I think mine is different. Theirs is effectively a radar plot; mine is intended to be pie wedges only. In other words, there's no information carried by the radial distance; only the length of the arc carries information.

Comment: Notice that I did not exercise my dupe hammer privileges. But I don't see any code that addresses the other deficiencies.

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg See https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/piechart-ggplot2.html for reproducible code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use geomtextpath to get the circular labels. Let's say we want to plot the seasons, equinoxes and solstices:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

df <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(c("2022-03-20 15:33", "2022-06-21 10:13",
                               "2022-09-23 02:03", "2022-12-21 21:47")),
           event = c("Vernal Equinox", "Summer Solstice",
                     "Autumnal Equinox", "Winter Solstice"))

seasons <- data.frame(xmin = c(-Inf, 2/12, 5/12, 8/12, 11/12),
                      xmax = c(2/12, 5/12, 8/12, 11/12, Inf),
                      ymin = 0, ymax = 0.95,
                      season = c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer",
                                 "Autumn", "Winter"))
```

The plotting code might look something like this:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = seasons,
            aes(xmin = xmin,xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = season),
            alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_textpath(data = data.frame(x = seq(0.5/13, 12.5/13, length = 12), 
                                  y = 1, label = month.name),
                aes(x, y, label = label), size = 6) +
  geom_textpath(data = data.frame(x = c(0.5/12, 3.5/12, 6.5/12, 9.5/12), y = 0.8,
                                  season = c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn")),
                aes(x, y, color = season, label = season), size = 10,
                alpha = 0.5, fontface = 2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0.95, 1.05)) +
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = seq(0, 12/13, length = 12),
    xend = seq(0, 12/13, length = 12),
    y = 0.95, yend = 1.05), aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_textsegment(data = df,  aes(x = lubridate::decimal_date(date) %% 1,
                   xend = lubridate::decimal_date(date) %% 1,
                   y = 0, yend = 0.95, label = event), vjust = -0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Winter = "deepskyblue4",
                               Spring = "yellowgreen",
                               Summer = "gold",
                               Autumn = "brown")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Winter = "deepskyblue4",
                               Spring = "yellowgreen",
                               Summer = "gold",
                               Autumn = "brown")) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.05)) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

For the re-creation of the liturgical calendar linked in the comments, we can do something like this:

```r
library(geomtextpath)
library(dplyr)

decimal <- function(x) lubridate::decimal_date(x) %% 1

Seasons <- Seasons %>% 
  mutate(Start_Date = decimal(Start_Date),
         End_Date   = decimal(End_Date))
Seasons$Start_Date[1] <- -Inf
Seasons$End_Date[nrow(Seasons)] <- Inf


ggplot(Seasons) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = Start_Date, xmax = End_Date,
                ymin = 0, ymax = 0.95, fill = Season)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0.95, 1.05, 1.07)) +
  geom_segment(data = Separators, aes(x = x, xend = x, y = 0.95, yend = 1.07)) +
  geom_textpath(data = Months, aes(x = Date, y = pos, label = Month),
                fontface = 2) +
  geom_textsegment(data = Events, 
                   aes(x = decimal(Date), xend = decimal(Date), 
                       y = 0, yend = 0.95, label = Event), vjust = 1.1, 
                   hjust = 0.95) +
  geom_textpath(data = data.frame(x = c(0.7, 0.22), y = 0.8, 
                label = c("Time after Pentecost", "Lent")), 
                aes(x, y, label = label, group = x), spacing = 500) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = Season_Colours) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = 2)) +
  ggtitle("THE LITURGICAL YEAR")
```

[image]

---

**Liturgical data**

```r
Events  <- data.frame(Event = c("Epiphany", "Ash Wednesday", 
                                "Easter Sunday", "Ascension", "Pentecost", 
                                "Trinity Sunday", "1st Sunday of Advent", 
                                "Immaculate Conception", "Christmas Day", 
                                "Epiphany"),
                      Date  = as.POSIXct(
                        c("2022-01-06", "2022-03-02", 
                          "2022-04-17", "2022-05-26", "2022-06-06", 
                          "2022-06-12", "2022-11-27", "2022-12-08", 
                          "2022-12-25", "2023-01-06")))

Seasons <- data.frame(Season = c("Christmas", "Time after Epiphany", 
                      "Septuagesima", "Lent", "Easter",
                      "Pentecost", "Time after Pentecost", 
                      "Advent", "Christmas"),
           Start_Date = as.POSIXct(c("2021-12-25",
             "2022-01-06", "2022-02-13", "2022-03-02",
             "2022-04-17", "2022-06-06", "2022-06-12",
             "2022-11-27", "2022-12-25"
           )),
           End_Date = as.POSIXct(c("2022-01-06",
             "2022-02-13", "2022-03-02",
             "2022-04-17", "2022-06-06", "2022-06-12",
             "2022-11-27", "2022-12-25", "2023-01-06"
           )))

Season_Colours <- c(`Time after Epiphany`  = "#7dca64",
                    Septuagesima           = "#896d96",
                    Lent                   = "#896d96",
                    Easter                 = "white",
                    Pentecost              = "#df0f33",
                    `Time after Pentecost` = "#7dca64",
                    Advent                 = "#896d96",
                    Christmas              = "white")

Months <- data.frame(Month = toupper(month.name),
                     Date  = seq(0.5/13, 12.5/13, length = 12),
                     pos   = 1)

Separators <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 12/13, length = 12))
```

Comment: Haha. Great Jon Allan. I already guessed that this is the kind of question or problem where one (or at least I) would expect an answer by you. And thought that would be a great opportunity to check your and teunbrand's  `geomtextpath` package. My current status: A pie + a donut without any curved labels. D:

Comment: Does this mean that I would have to enter my "key events" (e.g., the start/stop dates for seasons) as months starting at 1 January? I was hoping to have a data frame with two columns: Event (string) and Date (date), and then populate the pie with that.

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg you could do it that way if you wanted, perhaps with a little wrapper function. I'm happy to demo that if you like.

Comment: Hi Karl. I tried sending you an email, but it says your email inbox is undergoing maintenance.

Comment: @AllanCameron - That's odd. I just checked and email from another address went through. In any case, I put the data in this GitHub repo: https://github.com/Doc-Midnight/CircularChart

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg see my edit. I have included a tidied version of your data that allows for the plot to be re-created. You may want to add some items and tweak it a bit, but hopefully you have enough there to get you started.