# Asthetics for coxcomb plot r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I a using a coxcomb plot to plot the time of day (24-hour), depth class (factor) and the number of events. I have the plot but am unsure how to get the numbers around the plot - like a clock face and the y axis scale bar on the side. I would also like to get shading for dawn, dusk, day and night. Below is my code, sample data and current image. Thank you

```
ggplot(depthinside) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Sunlight.adj, fill = depthclass), width = 1) +
  labs(x=NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
  coord_polar()
```

```
> depthinside
   Event.number depthclass Sunlight.adj
1            11       Deep           15
2            26        Mid            6
3            27    Shallow           11
4            28    Shallow           12
5            29        Mid           13
6            30        Mid           13
7            31    Shallow           14
8            32    Shallow           14
9            33    Shallow           21
10           34    Shallow           15
11           36       Deep           17
12           37       Deep           17
13           39        Mid           20
14           40        Mid           21
15           41        Mid            1
16           42    surface            8
17           45       Deep            5
18           59    Shallow            5
19           62        Mid           22
20           63        Mid            1
21           64    surface           16
22           69        Mid            9
23           70        Mid            9
```

[image: How my plot currently looks]

[image: How I want my plot to look (with my data)]

Comment: [This related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023419/is-it-possible-to-create-a-circular-timeline-plot-with-ggplot/71023749#71023749) might be helpful

Comment: Thank you for the link to the post, that has helped with the numbers but has not helped with placing colours behind the plot or why I don't have a y axis.

Comment: The linked post shows how to put colours behind the plot - that's what the `geom_rect` does.

Answer (score 1):

We can make the background with rectangular annotations of the appropriate colour using `annotate`. In terms of the y axis, your code specifically removes it y with your calls to `theme`.

Putting these changes together we can do something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(depthinside) +
  annotate(geom = 'rect', xmin = 6, xmax = 19, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
           fill = 'yellow', alpha = 0.75) +
  annotate(geom = 'rect', xmin = 5, xmax = 6, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
           fill = 'orange') +
  annotate(geom = 'rect', xmin = 19, xmax = 20, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
           fill = 'orange') +
  annotate(geom = 'rect', xmin = 20, xmax = 24, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
           fill = '#35205A', alpha = 0.8) +
  annotate(geom = 'rect', xmin = 0, xmax = 5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
           fill = '#35205A', alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Sunlight.adj, fill = depthclass), width = 1,
           color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_brewer(direction = -1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3), breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 24), breaks = 0:23, name = '') +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.line.x.bottom = element_blank())
```

[image]